# SQL Server: Returning different number of rows from the same source data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have encountered today by far the most strange behaviour of SQL Server 2008 for me so far (or maybe I was already too tired to figure out what is going on).

I have a fairly complicated statement operating on around 1,100,000 rows. My source data is in table used by the subquery and it doesn't change. The statement looks something like this (I'll include only the parts that could cause the error in my opinion):

```
SELECT 
   -- here are some columns straight from the subquery and some hardcoded columns like
   'My company' AS CompanyName
   -- and here is the most important part
   SUM(Subq.ImportantFloatWithBigPrecision)
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    -- Here are some simple columns fetched from table and after that:
    udf.GetSomeMappedValue(Value) AS MappedValueFromFunction
    ,ImportantFloatWithBigPrecision
  FROM MyVeryBigTable
  WHERE ImportantFloatWithBigPrecision <> 0
    AND(...)
) Subq
GROUP BY everything except SUM(Subq.ImportantFloatWithBigPrecision)
HAVING SUM(Subq.ImportantFloatWithBigPrecision)<>0
ORDER BY (...)
```

I've checked the subquery quite a few times and it returns the same results every time, but the whole query returns 850-855 rows from the same data! Most of the time (around 80%) it is 852 rows, but sometimes its 855, sometimes 850 and I really have no idea why.

Surprisingly removing the `<> 0` condition from the subquery helped at first glance (so far 6 times I got the same results), but it has drastic impact on performance (for this amount of rows it runs about 8-9 mins longer (remember the udf? :/)

Could someone explain this to me? Any ideas/questions? I'm completely clueless...

**EDIT (inspired by Crono):** We're running this on two environments: dev and test and comparing the results so maybe some of the settings may differ.

**EDIT 2:** Values of ImportantFloatWithBigPrecision are from a really wide range (around -1,000,000 to + 1,000,000) but there are 'few' (propably in this scale around 25k-30k) rows which have values really close to 0 (first non-zero digit on 6-th place after separator, some start even further) both negative and positive.

Comment: Sounds obvious enough to me: between queries you are making something somewhere writes in the db and change the value of `ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision` or whatever other field you might check upon in your where clause... or am I missing something?

Comment: No, the source data is always the same and SUM of every ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision is the same in the source table/subquery/final query. We've benn checking only the SUM until now and everything seemed to be working fine. I believe that it has something to do when this ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision is 0, but I have clearly no idea anymore.

Comment: Does your UDF changes the data in any way?

Comment: Also, do you have null values anywhere? This may be having something to do with ANSI_NULL settings that could be different from one session to another.

Comment: No, it is quite complicated, but it is basically one big IF...THEN...ELSE statement. And it returns a Varchar value (running subquery alone gives the same results every time)

Comment: Then I'm as clueless as you are, I'm afraid. :p I'll favorite this, though, as I'm very curious... :)

Comment: Aren't these setting set once for whole DB? What are other settings I should take a look at? We're running this on two enviroments: dev and test and comparing the results so maybe some of the settings may differ.

Comment: What is querying the database? Have you checked with Sql Profiler to make sure the queries are exactly as you think they are?

Comment: ANSI_NULL can be very tricky. It can apply to a session but it also applies to the table upon creation or alteration and stays that way afterwards, regardless of the session settings thereafter. I've stumbled against that myself in the past. A good way to work around it is to use `ISNULL([whatever], 0)` function as a replacement for direct field access. Therefore, in your case: `SUM(ISNULL(ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision , 0))`

Comment: We're running some SSIS packages on top of that and based on the results I'm fairly certain that the queries are the same, but I didn't trace in in Profiler simply because at first I was thinking that it;d be some stupid issue and second because it could take a while for me to obtain profiler (working on a remote VM)

Comment: Other column can be NULL but this value must not be NULL (only 0).

Comment: What happens if you just run the select, without the UDF?

Comment: Are you using where conditions on other columns that are nullable? If so that could be it. If for example you have something like `column <> 1`, depending on ANSI_NULL setting this condition could be true or false when column value is null.

Comment: The ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision is of type Decimal or of type Float? There are values that are really near 0 that can lead to approximation error when confronted with 0? (What happen if you try to run the subquery with WHERE ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision = 0?)

Comment: @Crono yes, there are some WHERE conditions on nullable columns, but as I've said before the subquery itself always returns the same rows both on dev and test.

Comment: @Serpiton I'm leaning towards something like that. These are decimals with precision about 12 or 13 (I don't remeber), but some values are really near 0 (like first non-zero didigt is on 6th place after the separator). It could be the case if approximation happens on GROUP BY stage and it truncates the values itself and this way groups differently. But it'd have to round the values differently for number of rows returned to be different. And if it works like that is there any way to fix it in this case?

Comment: And these values can be really close to **both** sides of 0. Really small negative and positive values can happen (but most of the values is much greater than 0).

Comment: Just two silly ideas you can try to test the behaviour of your query: 1. explicitly cast the 0 in the condition to the same decimal definition of ImportantDecimalWithBigPrecision 2. change the field <> 0 with NOT(field = 0)

Comment: Just curious; are you running your select statement with NOLOCK or SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED?  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx

Comment: @Serpiton I'll try that on monday and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Great post, I wasn't aware of that. I'm not using any hints explicitly and I'm using default isolation levels for dev, but maybe someone changed it on test db. I'll have to check that on monday too.

Comment: Update: the ImportantDecimal is actually a float...

Comment: Non-deterministic query results are not unexpected in general. Here, the float comparison to 0 is especially suspicious. Are these floats *really* guaranteed to be exactly zero? Note, that with IEEE floats a + (b + c) is not necessarily equal to (a + b) + c. Reordering of operations can change the results slightly. Change the test with 0 to a range test: x between -1e-6 and 1e-6.